# Is there an intuitive noun for this type of business transaction

Tags: business-language, concision, intuition

In the domain I am working in (business accounting), I'm struggling to find a term to explain an event which takes place.

Supposing we have two sides to this business accounting we want to represent:

- your cash movements at the bank
- your cash movements with goods and service providers (which usually relate to the cash movements)

In a split screen, I have "Bank Transactions" on the left hand side. On the right is where I'm confused and currently have "Trading Partner Transactions".

I'm not confident with this as "Trading Partner Transactions" does not seem intuitive to the user. It could also include employee wage transactions, which are not really "trading partners".

Comment: I would have said "Vendor Transactions," until I read that you were including wage transactions.  Employees aren't providers in this sense, are they?  You should use something standard.  What does say, QuickBooks use?

Comment: I'd just call them ***Banking** [records]* and *[financial] **Transactions***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers has it.